# What does the third input to rand mean?

Tags: matlab

In the MATLAB if:

```
x = rand(a,b,c);
```

What does the third input to `rand`, `c`, mean?

`a`: numbers of rows

`b`: numbers of columns

`c`: ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MATLAB, matrices are not limited to 2 dimensions (i.e. only rows and columns), but can have many [higher dimensions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html?refresh=true).

The *third* input to the `rand` function is just telling `rand` the size of the *third* dimension that you want. By default it is `1`, but in your case it will instead be `c`.

In general, the *nth* input to `rand` will be the size of the *nth* dimension of the matrix of random numbers it produces.

Answer (score 1):

See the [docs](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html):

> `X = rand(sz1,...,szN)` returns an sz1-by-...-by-szN array of random
>   numbers where sz1,...,szN indicate the size of each dimension. For
>   example, rand(3,4) returns a 3-by-4 matrix.